# Retrieving Post Data sent from AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: php, post, afnetworking-3, afhttpsessionmanager

I am trying to retrieve the POST data sent using AFSessionManager but cannot access the POST ($_POST['param']) data. I can, however, retrieve the GET ($_GET['param'])) when sending a GET command. Please help!

xcode:

```
NSString *baseURL = baseURLIn;
NSDictionary *parameters = inputKeys;

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager =[[AFHTTPSessionManager manager]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: baseURL]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =  [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/xml"];
[manager POST:@"" parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"re:%@, keys=%@", responseObject, parameters);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"h=%@",error);
}];
```

php:

```
if($_POST){
  die(json_encode(array('e'=>$_POST['email'], 't'=>'emailAddress')));
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue and have tried multiple solutions that do not work

Comment: please let me know if you come across a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code listed above and documented at cocoadocs.org for AFNetworking are correct.

My error was in the URL string. my domain was being very specific about adding the "www" in front of the url.

If you are stuck, try this!